# What hardware do I need to use a Kinect model 1414 with a Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro

Want to use a Kinect model 1414 on a Mac. I know I need a power adapter, but will it just plug directly into USB or do I need some other adapter there as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided here: http://blog.nelga.com/setup-microsoft-kinect-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/
no additional hardware is required. A lot of software is though. Good luck!